# Usecase of an reference to scalar in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm learning perl references, I understand the usefullness of the references to hases or arrays. But thinking about in what scenarios can be useful a reference to an scalar value.

```
my $x = 1;
my $sr = \$x;
```

where can be useful to use `$$sr`, instead of direct use of `$x`?

For example, when traversing any deep hashref structure, isn't the common practice returning a reference if the given node is hashref or arrayref, but returning directly the scalar value instead of returning a reference to the scalar?

Exists some functions or modules what uses or return references to scalars, instead of returning the scalar's value?

Comment: why to use the reference of a scalar? In common I always use reference to arrays or hash map or some else more complexity struct which is combined with basic type. I think you also have the idea why to use references? yes, it's in order to reduce the price of value copying in complier that is also be seen in other program languages such as c++. although you can use a reference of scalar, but there is nearly no promotion to complier in the level of run time. Don't care something that most people don't use.

Comment: Sadly, just found myself, in asking an "wrong question" what is "opinion based" and can't choose the "best anser", all is good. Sorry for this.

Comment: It's a good question. The other's answer is more better than me. I really think there are so many common points between different languages. so in essence reference also have the same meaning to pointer in C or reference in C++, no special in perl. that's my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a subroutine, when you want to directly modify the values being passed into it.

e.g.

```
sub increment_this {
     my ( $inc_ref ) = @_;
     ${$inc_ref}++;
}
```

Bit of a trivial case I know, but perhaps more pertinent would be examples like `chomp` which removes trailing letters from a variable or `$_`.

If you think about it though - `$_` is often effectively a reference. 
If you do this:

```
my @array = qw ( 1 2 3 );
foreach ( @array ) {
    $_++;
}

print @array;
```

Modifying `$_` has modified the contents of the array.

Comment: `$_` is alias thus not happiest example for OP.

Comment: YES! the `increment_this` is an nice example. That doesn't comes to my mind. Thanx.

Comment: but it should be `${$inc_ref}++;` .. or no?

Comment: @kobame Incrementation is a poor example, IMO, since there already exists the `++` operator. :D I don't think there is a good example of a case where you would expect the original variable to be altered when passing it to a sub. In most cases, it is more logical to use the return value: `$foo = mysub($foo)`.

Comment: I was accepterd this not because of incrementation, but because allow modify the scalar what is outside of the sub... so passed by ref - but yes, the `$foo = sub($foo)` is much nicer...

Comment: @kobame - well spotted. Yes, fixed the bracketing. 
Increment is a trivial example - the one most will be familiar with is `chomp`. But the key point I think, is the use case for 'transform' styles of subroutines.

Comment: Stuff like Encode's functions use this. They do inplace-alteration. Another example is if you have an object that only has a single value. Damian Conway shows this in his book *Object Oriented Perl* in chapter 4.4.2 on the example of a password object, where it's about encapsulating related stuff in one place.

Answer (score 3):

I think the real answer lies in your question itself: *References to scalars are not terribly useful*, and you can probably just ignore that they exist when writing code. The main usefulness [as hinted at by perreal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742011/725418) is that you can point to the same memory location: Share a variable between objects.

However, for curiosity and academic purposes, one rather obscure thing comes to mind, besides the good examples left by perreal and Sobrique. You can open a file handle to print to a variable:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $string;
open my $fh, ">", \$string or die $!;
print $fh "Inside the string";

print Dumper $string;
# prints $VAR1 = 'Inside the string';
```

Comment: +1, References are older than this feature, and `\my $string` is perhaps more terse.

Comment: @mpapec Perhaps. I always think it looks odd to put a reference on a function rather than on the variable.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to share a scalar between objects:

```
my $v = 1;
my %h1 = (a=>\$v);
my %h2 = (b=>\$v);   
$v++;
print ${$h1{a}}, "\n";
print ${$h2{b}}, "\n";
```

*prints:*

```
2
2
```

Comment: Inside-out objects, but that was before Moose, http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2006-03-31.html

Comment: @mpapec thank you for prepared me another several hours of panic, while trying to understand "inside-out" objects. :) :) :)

Comment: I think inside out objects were something recommended in "Perl Best Practice" as a way of discouraging lazy coders from directly tinkering with object attributes. It's not much use any more, because if you're doing it on a small enough scale, it's irrelevant, and if you're doing it on a large enough scale, there's better ways of doing it.

Comment: @kobame it is a blessed scalar which hides object attributes in a way so they are not visible to outside of a class (attributes are stored inside lexical class variables and accessed via scalar used as key to hash).

Comment: @Sobrique yes, something like that.

Answer (score 1):

It is usefull when you have to pass huge strings to a sub, and don't want to do a copy of them to make faster and don't waste the memory:

```
sub my_sub {
    my $str = shift;  #makes a copy of a reference => cheaper
    #do something with $$str
}

#...
$x = ' ... large string ...';
my_sub(\$x);
```

Comment: That is not useful when you can just use `$_[0]` instead. Sounds more confusing than useful.

Comment: @TLP I'm not sure of this, as API actually hints what it could do with such reference.

Comment: You mean that it would avoid people accidentally changing their original variables? Like they try to do `my $new = mysub($old)`?

Comment: @TLP I mean that when using a function, *I don't expect* that `mysub($old)` should somehow alter `$old` var, while `mysub(\$old)` makes me think.

Comment: I'd agree - I think it'd be very dirty coding to write subs that tampered with their arguments. I mean, just because you _can_ to it, doesn't mean you _should_. And that's particularly true with Perl, which'll let you get away with all sorts of sordid behaviour. 
Explicit passing of references makes clear my expectation that this sub will adjust whatever's in that reference.

Comment: In recent versions of Perl with decent copy-on-write support, `my $x = $some_long_string` barely uses any additional memory. The two scalars point to the same area of memory.

Comment: @tobyink Can you elaborate on that? How does that work?

Comment: @TLP, with copy-on-write, making a copy of a variable doesn't copy the storage area - the two variables point to the same area of memory. However, once you *write* to one of the variables (causing the two to contain different data), it's obvious they can no longer use the same memory, so a copy is made. [Demonstration here](http://gist.github.com/99a1b6808392e35a3c68). Another example of the COW mechanism is Linux' implementation of `fork`: when a process forks, both copies continue to use the same memory until one of them starts to write to it. [Wikipedia: COW](http://enwp.org/Copy-on-write).

Comment: @tobyink That is a clever feature. In this case, however, I think the whole point is to alter the copy. It would be nice for this case if it just stored the changes between strings.

Comment: If it just stored the changes, this would use less memory, but string operations would require more CPU because you'd need to calculate which parts of the string are which. This is one of those places where there's a trade-off between CPU and memory.

Answer (score 0):

@TLP mentioned file handles, which prompted another example:

Passing around file handles. Good practice for manipulating files is to use lexical file handles, to avoid namespace pollution.

```
sub write_header {
  my ( $fh_ref ) = @_;
  print ${$fh_ref} "This is a header\n"; 
}

open ( my $output, ">", "output_filename" );
write_header ( \$output );
write_content ( \$output );
write_footer ( \$output );
close ( $output );
```

Comment: You can just use the file handle directly, though.

Comment: Reference to typeglob may have sense, but not to lexical file handle.